# how to make hyperlink to label in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to make a hyperlink of label in zend form. I agree to the Terms and Privacy policy make terms and condition to be link.

My code is:-

```
$this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Checkbox',
            'name' => 'agreeterms',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'I agree to the <a href="http:google.com">Terms and Privacy policy</a>',
                'use_hidden_element' => true,
                'checked_value' => 1,
                'unchecked_value' => 'no',
                'id'=>'term_and_condition',
            ),
        ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split label and input field in the view:

```
$this->formLabel($this->form->get('agreeterms'));
$this->formText($this->form->get('agreeterms'));
```

Then you can wrap the `<a href="..."> ... </a>` around it.

Comment: It would be cleaner by defining a specific renderer for this form element.

Comment: @Unex  Is there an example?